# Alphanumeric View in Android

Tags: android, user-interface

I am developing an Android App which gives users an option 'Browse Alphanumerically'. Using this option let users view the list of items starting with a particular letter or number. Problem is that I cannot decide how to implement screen for this, which can work properly on any screen size. Please suggest me the best solution.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the question? What kind of view to use? I suppose you want a ListActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I got from your question is that you want to show all alphabets and numbers to the user so they can jump directly to a entries start with the selected alphabet or number. If this is so, then one solution to your problem is use the Button or ImageButton any make a key pad of all alphabet and numbers. Don't forget to make them flexible enough for different screen sizes. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list activity. There are lots of tutorials on Google's developer site. When you want to narrow the list, just assign the smaller list to the ListView. Just filter your master list, sort it, and assign it to your list adapter.

Hope this was helpful.